# Reaction of 3-Chloropyridine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, heterocyclic-compounds

I've given a question , 3-chloropyridine + NaNH2  gives out A . Compound A on further reaction with furan gives compound B.

What I think now , First step is simple elimination addition reaction .
So A should be 3-Aminopyridine . Next step is little bit confusing to me.
I think product B should be nucleophilic substituted at 2-position of Furan by -NH2 group of 2-amniopyridine .

Comment: Think you've got this wrong.  I doubt sodamide displaces chloride from the 3 position (2 or 4 much more possible). I think it far more likely it is acting as a strong base.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryne